# count occurrences of every character per every line position in perl

Tags: perl, hashmap, idioms

Similar to question 
[unix - count occurrences of character per line/field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629410/unix-count-occurrences-of-character-per-line-field)
 but for every character in every position on the line.

Given a file of ~500-characters per 1e7 lines,
I want a two dimensional summary structure like
$summary{'a','b','c','0','1','2'}[pos 0..499] = count_integer
that shows the number of times each character was used in each position of the line. Either order of dimensions is fine.

My first method did ++summary{char}[pos] while reading,
but since many lines are the same,
it was much faster to count identical lines first,
then summarize summary{char}[pos] += n at a time

Are there more idiomatic or faster ways than the following C-like 2d loop?

```
#!perl 
my ( %summary, %counthash ); # perl 5.8.9

sub method1 {
    print "method1\n";
    while (<DATA>) {
        my @c = split( // , $_ );
        ++$summary{ $c[$_] }[$_] foreach ( 0 .. $#c );
    }    # wend
} ## end sub method1

sub method2 {
    print "method2\n";
    ++$counthash{$_} while (<DATA>);    # slurpsum the whole file

    foreach my $str ( keys %counthash ) {  
        my $n = $counthash{$str};
        my @c = split(//, $str);
        $summary{ $c[$_] }[$_] += $n foreach ( 0 .. $#c );
    }    #rof  my $str
} ## end sub method2

# MAINLINE
if (rand() > 0.5) { &method1 } else { &method2 }
print "char $_ : @{$summary{$_}} \n" foreach ( 'a', 'b' );
# both methods have this output summary
# char a : 3 3 2 2 3 
# char b : 2 2 3 3 2 
__DATA__
aaaaa
bbbbb
aabba
bbbbb
aaaaa
```

Comment: It's quite hard to visualise what you're looking for with that sample data - I assume your scenario isn't quite as trivial as a line full of repeated characters?
Also: `use strict; use warnings;` is a really good idea.

Comment: The only inefficiency/non-idiomaticity(?) I see is that you're counting all the line-termination characters (newlines and/or CRs) as well. (Perl includes them in `$_` unless you do something.) Stick in a `chomp;` after each `<DATA>` read.

Comment: @JeffY: *unidiomaticity*, I believe

Comment: Are these DNA sequences?

Comment: The real data is TDL, a form of VHDL vector using characters HLCM01Z, and I'm looking for which pins/columns are used vs static. I have use warning; use strict; in the real program, but I neglected to include them in the sample program for posting. Sobrique.      Jeff Y   Borodin

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your data is formed method2 might be a bit faster or slower than method 1.

But a big difference would be to use unpack instead of split.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( %summary, %counthash ); # perl 5.8.9

sub method1 {
    print "method1\n";
    my @l= <DATA>;
    for  my $t(1..1000000) {
        foreach (@l) {
            my @c = split( // , $_ );
            ++$summary{ $c[$_] }[$_] foreach ( 0 .. $#c );
        }    
    }    # wend
} ## end sub method1

sub method2 {
    print "method2\n";
    ++$counthash{$_} while (<DATA>);    # slurpsum the whole file
    for  my $t(1..1000000) {
        foreach my $str ( keys %counthash ) {  
            my $n = $counthash{$str};
            my $i = 0;
            $summary{ $_ }[$i++] += $n foreach ( unpack("c*",$str) );
        }    
    }
} ## end sub method2

# MAINLINE
#method1();
method2();
print "char $_ : ". join (" ", @{$summary{ord($_)}}). " \n"
    foreach ( 'a', 'b' );
# both methods have this output summary
# char a : 3 3 2 2 3 
# char b : 2 2 3 3 2 
__DATA__
aaaaa
bbbbb
aabba
bbbbb
aaaaa
```

runs much faster. (6 instead of 7.x seconds on my pc)

Comment: Did you test that?  {unpack("c*",$str)}  generates the wrong summary keys of 98 and 97, rather than 'a' and 'b';  'a*' does not work;THIS WORKS: $summary{ $_ }[$i++] += $n foreach ( unpack('a' x length($str),$str) ); THIS ALSO WORKS $summary{ chr($_)}[$i++] += $n foreach ( unpack('c*',$str) );

Comment: <br/>$summary{ substr($str,$_,1) }[$_] += $n foreach ( 0..(length($str)-1)); # IS EQUALLY AS FAST

Comment: @jgrabber yes i did and it worked. unpack just returns the invert of chr so in my code i print sumary{ord($_)} as you might have noticed...

But.. the solution with length and substring is even faster. The original code (executed a million time) takes 7.177 secs on my pc, the solution with unpack takes 5.879 secs and the solution with length and substring takes only 4.286 secs.

Comment: > so in my code i print sumary{ord($_)} as you might have noticed.

Comment: comment timeout : @Georg Just 1 b in jgraber :  Not until you pointed it out did I notice the ord in the print.   In a similar application to get data for just user-input columns, the fastest approach I have seen is building the code for a bunch of substr() into a string, then evalling it to get a compiled subroutine,  then call that.       Re perlidioms, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1868490/5650997) demonstrates use of map for a similar loop.      Maybe not until perl6 would there be a way to  add to 2d slices;   @summary{ slice} [0..m] ^+= $n x (slice * m);